# Passing data to view when using redirect in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, variables, view, set, cakephp-1.3

I have two forms on a single view edit profile and change password. I have set the changepassword form action to changePassword and I am using

```
$this->autoRender = false; 
$this->render("index");
$this->redirect("index#chngPassTab");
```

but I am not able to set some varible to view due to redirection. I don't want to use session. 
All I want to set some variables based on conditions in controller action, get these variable values in view and when page reloaded after postback the password tab should be selected for that I used `$this->redirect("index#chngPassTab");`

Please guide me best way to fix this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would;t be easier to set up a jquery  to handle the changes based on data you parse to a view?

so, for example after you do a post your `$whatever_variable` is set

then in your view

```
<script>
 <?php if(!empty($whatever_variable): ?>
     $('.tabs').tabs('select', '#chngPassTab');; //or whatever plugin yu are using
<?php endif?>
</script>
```

EDIT: my bad, just reread your question and reliased that your post action is different then your view. In that case post to index controller and then from index controller call changepassowrd action, which returns whatever you want it to return. or, use sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the function of the controller:

```
$this->set('name_of_variable', {YOUR DATA HERE});
```

Then in the view, you can access the variable:

```
<?php echo $name_of_variable; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do some processing in the index controller when you redirect to it. Any items that were saved when you processed the form would be available in the database and if you are processing something based on the url you could do that before render.

Plus:

```
$this->autoRender(false);
```

would stop your controller from rendering, but then calling

```
$this->render("index");
```

would try to render your index view, but calling

```
$this->redirect("index#chngPassTab");
```

would override it and redirect it, you only need to do the redirect in that case, the render call is being made useless.

Comment: Redirect takes an array URL or a relative string URL, yours is neither.

Comment: actually the string would be relative and tacked onto the end of whatever the referrer was. So if you were to say redirect("index") and you came from /posts/add it would take you to /posts/index. That wasn't really what I was commenting on. More so I was saying there is extra legwork being done that is doing nothing.

Comment: Sorry I am not using any data from database. Just showing some error message if data is invalid. Cannot I pass #chngPassTab in $this->render("index"); so that password tab should be selected because jquery tab needs this to know which tab should be selected

Answer (score 0):

Http is stateless by design. If you redirect the data for the last request is gone. This is why sessions were invented.

If you want the data to show stop using redirect.

Also there is no point to calling render and the redirect as the render will never be rendered.

Comment: Yes it will show up the data but is there anythink i can do one view so that when submit button on the changepassword tab pressed and page reloads it should select changepassword tab. I am using jquery tab menus. it needs #changpassword parameter to select change password by default.

Comment: $this->Html->link('meh', array('action' => 'something', '#' => 'change password'));